# How I add Security to the smart contract?

Tags: myetherwallet, truffle-contract, ganache

I deployed this contract and also interacted with it using ganache.

```
     pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
    contract Counter {
     int private count = 0;
     function incrementCounter() public {
      count += 1;
      }
      function decrementCounter() public {
    count -= 1;
      }
      function getCount() public constant returns (int) {
    return count;
      }
    }
```

However, when interacting with the contract, any account on Ganache can interact with it and use the function increment. How can I define only one account from Ganache to be able to change this function ?? I just wanna to add some security to the contract?

This is link for the smartcontract I follow: https://medium.com/crypto-currently/build-your-first-smart-contract-fc36a8ff50ca

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `Ownable` library https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol . It gives you a modifier called `onlyOwner` which you can add to all the functions where you need to restrict the access.

Using the `onlyOwner` modifier blocks access from anyone but from the owner. Owner is by default the one who created the contract.

There are also other alternatives to this but `Ownable` is probably the most widely-used and accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a constraint to your functions, like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
    contract Counter {

        int private count = 0;
        address public admin;

        constructor() public {
            admin = msg.sender;
        }

        function incrementCounter() public {
            require(msg.sender==admin);
            count += 1;
        }

        function decrementCounter() public {
            require(msg.sender==admin);
            count -= 1;
        }

        function getCount() public constant returns (int) {
            return count;
        }
    }
```

In the constructor, the admin is set to be the account that deployed the contract. Then, the `require(msg.sender==admin)` will check if the account trying to execute the functions is the admin of your system, if not, it will throw and the function will not be executed.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `modifier` to the contract, then include the modifier wherever you want the added security. Below, the modifier `isAdmin` has been added to the `incrementCounter` and `decrementCounter` functions.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Counter {
    int private count = 0;

    modifier isAdmin() {
        require(msg.sender == 0xYOUR-ADDRESS-HERE);
        _;
    }

    function incrementCounter() public isAdmin {
        count += 1;
    }

    function decrementCounter() public isAdmin {
        count -= 1;
    }

    function getCount() public constant returns (int) {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it gives me this error ": Expected primary expression. require(msg.sender == 0x0x081D55360Acf2990791656c195Ee94124d84B186) ^-^" . How can I solve that error ?

Comment: you have an extra `0x`, should be `0x081D55360Acf2990791656c195Ee94124d84B186`

Comment: I added the public key corresponding to the private key which is used to deploy the contract, I get that error with the function that uses the mpdifier " the tx doesn't have the correct nonce. account has nonce of: 3 tx has nonce of: 2"

Comment: Public key?? I'm not very familiar with Ganache, but that sounds like a problem with your client. Probably best to ask a new question.